# Tomcat Server Failed

Tags: tomcat7

Hi mate's I have been using tomcat 7 but whenever I reboot the machine , the server fails to startup in myeclipse.. Its showing JVM bind exception and I tried to clear the error by changing the port number but it's no use. Again if I uninstall it and re install newly means its working fine in myeclipse, I have saw lots of blogs but still my issue is not sorted out. I have to reinstall my tomcat again and again whenever I restart my machine to make it work in myeclipse. I dont know whether its myeclipse problem or tomcat problem or system problem.. Please help me out.

Comment: Please add operating system, tomcat, jdk and myeclipse version info, what you describe is absolutely not normal, it could be caused by some unworkable version mix.

Comment: Have you check the environment variables on your system ? Install or uninstall may have not done the work you think it should do.

Comment: Yeah , I am using JDK 7 , Tomcat Server 7 and MyEclipse Professional 2014.